# Passing embedded object to nested component in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to to pass an embedded object to a nested component in angular 2.

**Here my model MyClassA :**

```
import {MyClassB} from "../myclassb/myclassb.model";

export class MyClassA {

attributeA: string;
embeddedObject : MyClassB;
myId : string;

constructor(attributeA: string, embeddedObject: MyClassB, myId?: string) {
    this.attributeA = attributeA;
    this.embeddedObject = embeddedObject;
    this.myId = myId;
}
}
```

My model ClassB is simple : many string attributes;

**Here my MyClassA-list component which list all MyClassA objects (getting it from Server, using service) :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {MyClassA} from "./myclassa.model";
import {MyClassAService} from "./myclassa.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-myclassa-list',
    template: `
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <app-myclassa
                   [myClassA]="myClassA"
                    *ngFor="let myClassA of myClassAs"></app-myclassa>
        </div>
    `
})
export class MyClassAListComponent implements OnInit {
    myClassAs: MyClassA[];
    constructor(private myClassAService: MyClassAService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.myClassAService.getAllMyClassA()
            .subscribe(
                (myClassAs: MyClassA[]) => {
                    this.myClassAs = myClassAs;
                }
            );
    }
}
```

**Here my MyClassA component, is simple :**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-myclassa',
    templateUrl: './myclassa.component.html'
})
export class MyClassAComponent {
    @Input() myClassA: MyClassA;

    constructor(private myClassAService: MyClassAService) {}
}
```

**And here the html template to display the component :**

```
<article class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{ myClassA.attributeA }} :
        {{ myClassA.embeddedObject.attributeX }}
    </div>
</article>
```

**myClassA.attributeA is correctly displayed, but the embeddedObject is empty.**
I saw with debugger that myClassAService returns correct object MyClassA with embedded object populated.

Someone know what's happens ?

Comment: Try {{ myClassA | json }} to see the object content

Comment: Thank you ! This help me to see my error. I dont know why it's the json attribute (from server) which is passed to the component and no the embeddedObject.attributeX (constructed in my Service) : I renamed the name of this attribute in my myClassB.